# Add class then remove on change of owl carousel

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel-2

I am detecting when my owl carousel changes, then firing my **change** function which simply gets the number of slide and adds a class to one of the parent divs.

```
function change(event) {
  // Listen to owl events:
  var item = event.page.index;
  $('.venue-whats-on').toggleClass('rotw-'+item+'');
}
```

At the moment, jquery is adding the class but when it changes again, the old class remains whilst it puts another.

```
<div class="venue-whats-on rotw-1 rotw-2 rotw-3">
```

How could I remove the previous **rotw-*** class and replace it with a new/next one?

Comment: Assuming there's a finite number of slides, you could use `removeClass('rotw-1 rotw-2 ... rotw-N')` for example, although the pattern you're using isn't ideal for this.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I did this approach as a temp and it's working. I will look to improve in future, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you store the added class for example in data-active. Then, when you are adding the new class to the container, you have the class to be removed and you can remove it. Then you save in data-active the new class